# Преобразовать строку в словарь списков c N количеством символов

Tags: python, строки

Дана строка:

```
result = 'X34-/1744XX23--4/'
```

на выходе должно выглядеть так:

```
{1:(X, -), 2:(3, 4), 3:(-, /), 4:(1, 7), 5:(4, 4), 6:(X, -), 7:(X, -), 8:(2, 3), 9:(-, -), 10:(4, /)}
```

проблема в том, что не могу понять, как подставить '-' после 'X'

Так как есть условие, что если в строке есть 'X', то после него должно быть всегда '-'

я делаю так:

```
result = 'X34-/1744XX23--4/'
analized_res = {}
for i, k in enumerate(zip(result[0::2], result[1::2]), start=1):
    analized_res[i] = k
print(analized_res)
```

на выходе:

```
{1: ('X', '3'), 2: ('4', '-'), 3: ('/', '1'), 4: ('7', '4'), 5: ('4', 'X'), 6: ('X', '2'), 7: ('3', '-'), 8: ('-', '4')}
```

Comment: Да будь проще. Воткни - после X в начальной строке, а потом уж режь

Comment: в этом случае это проще, но вхдящяя строка может меняться, и в теории может быть вида 'XXXXXXXXXX' а на выходе мне все равно надо {1: ('X', '-'), 2: ('X', '-'), 3: ('X', '-'), 4: ('X', '-'), 5: ('X', '-'), 6: ('X', '-'), 7: ('X', '-'), 8: ('X', '-'), 9: ('X', '-'), 10: ('X', '-')}

Comment: И? Програмно воткни, не в блокноте  же. Через result.replace('x', 'x-')

Comment: не пробовал такой вариант, но поидее, если строка уже войдет с х- она может стать х--?

Comment: Да станет, а не должна? По вашим условиям должна стать x--. Приведите зачачу полностью, если нет.

Comment: Да если нет, то можно сделать еще один реплэйс x-- на x-

Comment: Добавлю пример. Пусть есть строка result = 'X34-/1744XX23--4/'
Напишите функцию(а лучше метод), который примет параметром эту строку, а на выходе выдаст
# {1:(X, -), 2:(3, 4), 3:(-, /), 4:(1, 7), 5:(4, 4), 6:(X, -), 7:(X, -), 8:(2, 3), 9:(-, -), 10:(4, /)}
# Тогда можно будет легко проверить строку на наличие ошибок.
# Примеры фреймов с ошибками: (1, X) - страйк на втором броске
# (/, 2) - / на первом броске
# (5, 5) - сумма очков больше 9 (в этом случае должен быть (5, /)
# (0, 2) - вместо 0 должен быть "-"
# Так же надо проверять количесвто фреймов + наличие других символов в строке.

Comment: на самом деле я не знаю точно, может ли зайти строка уже с '-' после 'X' или нет... на данный момент воспользуюсь вашим советом! Спасибо

Comment: Если это боулинг, то второй бросок не делается после страйка. Надо ставить - всегда

Comment: да, он самый, ниже написал ответ, на основе вашего совета! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

этот код помог:

```
result = 'X34-/1744XX23--4/'
analized_res = {}
for x in result:
    for i, k in enumerate(zip(result.replace('X', 'X-')[0::2], result.replace('X', 'X-')[1::2]), start=1):
        analized_res[i] = k
print(analized_res)
```

на выходе:

```
{1: ('X', '-'), 2: ('3', '4'), 3: ('-', '/'), 4: ('1', '7'), 5: ('4', '4'), 6: ('X', '-'), 7: ('X', '-'), 8: ('2', '3'), 9: ('-', '-'), 10: ('4', '/')}
```